# Satellite image is cut when composite tool is run on it using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, image-mosaic

I am using satellite imagery in my project.  The images come in squares, after using composite to join the bands, one square shrinks or is clipped somehow.

Does anyone know the solution?

See the before and after pics.

Before:

[image]

After: The small green rectangle is what remains of the upper left square

[image]

Comment: Please describe your workflow in detail. Can you provide the data? Have you made sure you use the correct extent for the top left image?

Comment: Hi Erik, I ran the composite tool, extents same on all 4 panels (Landsat 8, 7 bands each). That is the only one that malfunctioned, I ended up using another, but still interested in what happened, so that I can prevent it or help other avoid it. I have another question in the offing.. so if you have time.. thank you

Comment: Extent means the spatial extent of the image.